# Devexpress grid with bootstrap modal slow loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, bootstrap-modal

I have created Devexpress grid in my asp.net application. The grid contains 10 columns. I have implemented double click event on a row, which displays bootstrap modal allowing edition of rows. However, the modal is loading very slowly (up to 10 seconds), even tough the request is very fast and open modal method is executing at the very beginning of a callback. After the few tests i'm almost sure that the problem persists on the devexpress code, however I have no idea what can be done to increase the performance of loading modal window.The problem persisted even when I was using empty dialog box instead of a modal.

Comment: Did you post this question on DevExpress support center? They generally respond to every question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Angular change detection strategy, which needed to be set to DetectChanges() instead of waiting for the inputs.